weblogic 12c error while start up : Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid
I did a mistake, changed weblogic admin console password without shutting down the admin instance.
Now while restart, I am seeing this error " Boot identity not valid". I decrypted the password in boot.properties file for admin instance, forms and reports managed instance, Its still the old one. Also on config.xml, for node manager, the password is still old one. Please help how can i rectify this issue
I wanted to changed the admin console password for weblogic 12c, but i did it without stopping the instance. Now after server reboot, the application is not coming up.
